# how to display checkbox multi-select in django

Tags: django, checkbox, multi-select

if I select all checkbox then my checkbox display only one thing
i want display multi select checkbox in django. what is problem in my code?

**in html**

```
<form action="" method="GET">
        <label style="color: gray;" >&nbsp; 확장자 -</label> 
            {% for extention in file_extention %}

                {% if extention.name == extention_name %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="extention_name" value="{{ extention.name }}" checked>{{ extention.name }}
                {% else %}
                <input type="checkbox" name="extention_name" value="{{ extention.name }}"> {{ extention.name }}
                {% endif %}

            {% endfor %}
    </form>
```

**in views.py**

````
if request.method == 'GET':
        png = {'name' : '.png'}
        jpg = {'name' : '.jpg'}
        gif = {'name' : '.gif'}
        
        file_extention = [png, jpg, gif]
        
        context = {}
        context['file_extention'] = file_extention

        extention_name = request.GET.get('extention_name',None)
        
        
        context['extention_name'] = extention_name
        
        return render(request, 'home/index.html',context)```
````

Answer (score 0):

You're currently breaking out of your IF statement when it hits the first match. Consider moving the if statement to within your input tag so each input tag in the loop is checked for matches. Something like this within your for loop should do it:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="extention_name" value="{{ extention.name }}" 
{% if extention.name == extention_name %}checked{% endif %}>
{{ extention.name }}
```